# How to transfer virtual machines from VMware Fusion to vSphere?

Tags: vmware-fusion, vcenter, vmware-converter

I have a virtual machine built by using *VMware Fusion v2.0* on OS X and I would like to move it to a *VMware vSphere* server (version unknown). What would be the best way to do this? From what I found on-line, it would be to convert the virtual machine into an appliance using vCenter Converter and import it on vSphere; but vCenter Converter doesn't run on OS X. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just learned about [OVF](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/getting-started/learn/ovf.html) for this.